# New Activity from RecyclerView ViewHolder stuck on blackscreen

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am trying to make a simple app in which you have a list of elements in a RecyclerView, and if you click on any you can see it in more details. Im stuck in how to start the new activity from inside the RecyclerView. I have tried many solutions found here but noone of them worked.

My new Activity never starts (i never see the Toast message on GroupActivity) and the app gets stuck on a black screen, but the listener is getting triggered because i see the message inside the onClick function.

I have checked my new activity is inside the AndroidManifest.xml and that i have the setContentView on the new activity

My new Activity, **GroupActivity.java**:

```java
    public class GroupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_group);
    
            Toast.makeText(this, "Started new activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
        }
        
    }
```

My activity_group.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white">
    
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello!"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My RecyclerView Adapter, **RecyclerAdapter.java**:

```java
    public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    
        private String data[];
        private Context context;
    
        public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, String[] data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.context = context;
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_item, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.textView.setText(data[position]);
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(this.context,"The Item Clicked is: " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GroupActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data.length;
        }
    
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder /*implements View.OnClickListener*/ {
    
            // private final Context context;
            TextView textView;
    
            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
                context = itemView.getContext();
                // itemView.setClickable(true);
                // itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
    
            /* @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"The Item Clicked is: " + getPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, GroupActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } */
        }
    }
```

As you can see from the commented lines, i have both tried adding an OnClickListener inside the ViewHolder and in the onBindViewHolder. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your listener getting triggered?

Comment: @dinkar_kumar Yes, i added a Toast message and when i click on one element the message pops up

Comment: But you said following in your question.
`My new Activity never starts (i never see the Toast message) and the app gets stuck on a black screen` , so which toast message shown to you by which you verified that your listener is working ?

Comment: @dinkar_kumar Not the toast message on the GroupActivity.java, i mean i added a Toast message inside the onClickListener in the onBindViewHolder method and that one is the one i see. I never see the one in the GroupActivity.onCreate method. Sorry for the confusion, let me edit my code

Comment: yes, you should always paste latest code or how else I will know what are you referring or talking about

Comment: @dinkar_kumar Code is updated, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: so it just stuck as black screen or anything happens after that I mean is it like ANR ?

Comment: @dinkar_kumar The app is not frozen because i can hit the back key and it returns to the main activity. I think its stuck trying to create the new activity, thus the black screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line

> context = itemView.getContext();

In ViewHolder. Because when you want intent you need a context of the activity, not an itemView.

It seems you change your themes. Go to res-> values-> themes-> themes.xml

Change:

```
<style name="Theme.Practica1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

To

```
<style name="Theme.Practica1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Then your Group Activity will be white.
You need to change your primary color to another color because of the toolbar and also Override onCreate method with only 1 parameter (Bundle)

Comment: No luck, still a blackscreen. I am making sure i pass the MainActivity context correctly and still doesnt work. I ended up removing it tho, since i can see the issue

Comment: If your project is open-source could you send your URL?

Comment: I have uploaded it to drive for you to download: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OXy4jNEjA4AdGPLmEQeg6TMf2OeXuVKb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Update my answer. Please check.

Comment: I did that and changed my Primary and seconday colors to pink and blue, so i could tell the difference. Now i get a white screen but i cant see the "Hello" in the textView in the GroupActivity. Did i misunderstand your answer?

Comment: Yeah, Please remove all android:background="@color/white" in RootView like activity_group.xml
then Override onCreate method with one parameter (Bundle) in GroupActivity instead of two parameters

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, i have been stuck on this for hours! You may edit your answer to include the only 1 parameter in the GroupActivity.onCreate. Thank you very much!